# How to use ActionBar sherlock ?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

How do I use actionbar sherlock in my android application? i have tried the website but had no sucess.. I want to have a background image,center the app name "no icon in the actionbar" I have tried [this code](http://tinyurl.com/pguqag5)  and the example in [this link](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) but im not understanding how to setup the code like the files and all. I could use some extra help also here is my download link https://www.dropbox.com/s/a8kwk1ao6ye56dr/Cydia.zip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how to use ActionBarSherlock:

1. Download the ActionBarSherlock [here](http://actionbarsherlock.com/download.html).
2. Assuming you're using Eclipse IDE, right click your Project, click Properties, then Android. At the bottom, in Layout, Add ActionBarSherlock.
3. Make sure ActionBarSherlock and your Project are in the same directory.
4. Extend your classes to Sherlock naming. For example, instead of Activity, change it to Sherlock Activity. The main documentation of ActionBarSherlock is found [here](http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html).
5. For easier usage of Sherlock, create util methods in changing the Sherlock names and modifying it.

Comment: could u give me more details about **util methods**?
What are they?

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain more briefly what do you want to do?

for centering the app name, you could **use** this answer:

[Set Title gravity to center in ActionBarSherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12125359/1932105)

Comment: i dont know like how to setup actionbar sherlock. i havent done it ever and im new to android programming so sorry for the noobish question i posted a link to my .zip hoping some one can download it and edit it for me..

Answer (score 1):

Analyze [these samples](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/master/actionbarsherlock-samples) slowly and carefully and everything will be okay :)

These samples cover how to use `ActionBarSherlock` in your project.